# How to delete Pseudo-elements with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pseudo-element

How do I delete pseudo-elements with jquery.
I tried before:

```
$('.myclass a:after').hide();
```

and it's not working like that.

Comment: can you please share your HTML also or post a JSFiddle ?

Comment: You can't modify pseudo element like that... but you can use a class based approach

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gvau5s0z/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the `pseudo elements` directly using scripts, but you can use some workarounds.

One of them is to use a class like

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.myclass a').addClass('hide-after');
})
```

```css
.myclass a:after {
  content: '++'
}
.hide-after:after {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">
  <a>something</a>
</div>
<button>Test</button>
```